# How to use json_serializable in flutter with markers to use them in a GoogleMap?

Tags: json, plugins, flutter, package, markers

I'm trying to use json_serializable with my class "Trail".

```
class Trail {
    String trailId;
    String trailName;
    String userID;
    String userName;
    double distanceInMeters;
    String description;
    int dificulty;
    int likes;
    List<Marker> markers;
    List<Vote> votesList;
    List<String> likedBy;
}
```

When I try the command:

```
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

I get this error:

```
Error running JsonSerializableGenerator
Could not generate `fromJson` code for `markers` because of type `Marker`.
None of the provided `TypeHelper` instances support the defined type.
```

How the hell do I make Markers serializable?

Answer (score 0):

easy my friend,
install a plugin json2dart if you are using android studio ,
,
now right click on lib folder -> new->json to dart (the last option)
.
paste your Jason object,
a sample of your json object to it,
give it a name and click generate,
a correctly mapped dart file will be created,
,
make a constructor for that class , and pass your values to it,
.
sending any data to the server as json ....
use json.encode(object)
.
'object' it is the object of that generated class